# How can I configure Octave to use gnuplot for plotting directly to image files?

Tags: debian, gnuplot, octave

I'm using Octave in a CLI only environment. I want to export plots to image files(jpg or png or any other image format). I read from manual that I can switch to gnuplot graphics by `graphics_toolkit(gnuplot)`.

I use the following commands in gnuplot to output a plot as file (as I can't use plot function in Octave due to absence of X11).

```
set terminal png
set output "test.png"

plot "data1.txt"

unset output
```

But I can't figure out a way to set `terminal` and `output` variables from Octave. So my question is how can I set those two variables from octave  so that running `plot` function from Octave generates a images file on my disk?

Note: I'm using Debian in an chroot environment which is completely CLI. So I use octave to generate data inside `"data.txt"` first and then use gnuplot to save my plots as image file . Later I view those plots in my host os(Android) with some image viewer.

Comment: use `figure("visible", "off")` after switching to gnuplot and before any plot command

Comment: Then how can i save plot to an image file? How can I set terminal?

Comment: hm? Just as normal: `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");figure("visible", "off"); plot(1:10); print foo.png`

Comment: If @Andy's solution doesn't work, you could call the gnuplot command from within Octave too: `fid = popen ("gnuplot","w"); fputs(fid,"set terminal png");` etc.

Comment: i have to issue print command each time i plot something... is it possible issue that (print test.png)automatically after plot command? I'm thinking about making a custom function which will issue `print` automatically after plot but  can't figure out how to pass a whole string(like "x,y,title,blah,blah,blah" ) from that custom function to plot... any suggestion? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andy for giving useful hints to solve this problem. So I ran those codes in interpreter and later put them in `.octaverc` for a permanent fix. Here's the code for a quick fix:
`graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
setenv ("GNUTERM", "png");
warning("off","print:missing_fig2dev");
warning("off","print:missing_epstool");`
Note  : When I ran plot command,it gave 2 warnings(not errors). I read [here](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/warning-print-m-epstool-binary-is-not-available-td4653216.html) that the warnings might be due in exclusion of fltk(as I'm using gnuplot in a cli only environment). The warnings didn't prevent me from plotting anything but those warnings appeared everytime I ran plot which annoyed me. So I put them in the rc file. Otherwise `plot` function is running fine.
Thanks @Cris Luengo for an alternate solution. But I haven't tried that actually.  ;)